# ksqldb nested SELECT without specifying fields or column renaming

Tags: join, apache-kafka, ksqldb

We have employer and address database tables that are streaming record changes to kafka topics.  We are running a pilot to replace some custom code with ksqldb.  We are planning on creating non-materialized ksqldb tables to mirror those topics, and then creating materialized tables for queries.  A truncated example is below:

```
CREATE TABLE `employer-non-materialized` (
 `guid` VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
 `name` VARCHAR,
 `address_guid` VARCHAR
 ) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'employer-topic',
  KEY_FORMAT = 'KAFKA',
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
);

CREATE TABLE `address-non-materialized` (
 `guid` VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
 `city` VARCHAR,
 `state` VARCHAR
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC = 'address-topic',
  KEY_FORMAT = 'KAFKA',
  VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
);

CREATE TABLE `employer` as SELECT * FROM `employer-non-materialized`;
CREATE TABLE `address` as SELECT * FROM `address-non-materialized`;
```

We want to join the data to create an `employer-address` topic:

```
CREATE TABLE `employer-address`
AS SELECT
  `employer`.`guid` as `guid`,
  `employer`.`name` as `name`,
  STRUCT(`city` := `address`.`city`, `state` := `address`.`state`) as `address`
FROM `employer`
 LEFT JOIN `address` ON `employer`.`address_guid` = `address`.`guid`
EMIT CHANGES;

// Outputs
{
  "guid": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "address": {
    "guid": "guid",
    "city": "string",
    "state": "string"
  }
}
```

This produces backwards-compatible output for our system, but creates additional schema maintenance.  When the upstream tables add new columns, we'd have to add new columns to the joined-view.  They wouldn't flow automatically through schema-registry. This alternative reduces schema management, but requires a sizable investment to migrate downstream consumers to the new format:

```
CREATE TABLE `employer-address`
AS SELECT
  *
FROM `employer`
 LEFT JOIN `address` ON `employer`.`address_guid` = `address`.`guid`
EMIT CHANGES;

// Outputs
{
  "employer_guid": "string",
  "employer_name": "string",
  "employer_address_guid": "string",
  "address_guid": "string",
  "address_city": "string",
  "address_state": "string"
}
```

Which brings me to my actual question: is there a way to get the best of both worlds?  This hypothetical syntax would ideally update the output when new columns appeared, eliminate prepending the table name to the columns, and nest the joined object all at once:

```
CREATE TABLE `employer-address`
AS SELECT
  `employer`.* AS *,
  STRUCT(`address`.*)
FROM `employer`
 LEFT JOIN `address` ON `employer`.`address_guid` = `address`.`guid`
EMIT CHANGES;

// Should output
{
  "guid": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "address": {
    "guid": "guid",
    "city": "string",
    "state": "string"
  }
}
```

Much thanks for reading this far :)

Comment: We could imagine a sub-query to get the parts of the adresse which we can use in the struct but how will we know whether a new column should be a field of the adress or a first level column in the output?

Comment: ksqldb doesn't support subqueries - https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/745